# R-Leaflet: Plotted points on wrong country

Tags: r, leaflet

I am learning the leaflet package and am running into a snag. To learn the package I am using the Snow deaths dataset from the package HistData which contains historic Cholera deaths from an epidemic.

When I run the following code the deaths plot correctly put the map layer underlying the dots is Africa rather than London. Any tips on correcting this?

```
# John Snow Cholera data
library(leaflet)
library(HistData)
library(sp)

data(Snow.deaths)
coordinates(Snow.deaths) <- x+y
proj4string(Snow.deaths) <- CRS("+init=epsg:3109")

leaflet(Snow.deaths) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addCircles(lng = ~y, lat = ~x, weight = 1,
             radius = ~3000, popup = ~case
  )
```

Comment: My guess would be a problem with the coordinates. Can you post your data?

Comment: would be happy too. Is there a way to upload data using this site? or should I just paste an extract  in the comments ? alternatively if you are ok with installing a package the data is : library(HistData) data(Snow.deaths)

Answer (score 3):

`help(Snow.deaths)` says:

```
 The scale of the source map is approx. 1:2000.  The ‘(x, y)’
 coordinate units are 100 meters, with an arbitrary origin.
```

so I don't know why you think EPSG:3109 is going to help you, that seems to be Jersey transverse mercator... http://epsg.io/3109

To properly georeference these you'll need to find the lat-long of the arbitrary origin and construct a `proj4` string with that origin. The small spatial range of the data probably means a transverse mercator will do the job.

Or you could find a readily-georeferenced John Snow cholera data set... I'm sure there's one about....

http://blog.rtwilson.com/john-snows-cholera-data-in-more-formats/

might help.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I will try and find a geo-referenced dataset.